calculus of variations over the class of lipschitz function
If we have a random variable $X \sim U(0,1)$ with probability density function $f_X(x)\in[0,1]$, we might be interested in solving the following optimization problem:
$$
\max_g \ \mathbb{E} \left[ g\left( X \right) \right] = \int_0^1{g\left( x \right) f_X\left( x \right) \mathrm{d}x}
$$
subject to the constraints:
$$
g\left( 0 \right) = 0, \quad 0 \le g'\left( x \right) \le 1
$$
The condition restricted the space of non-negative, non-decreasing, and 1-lipschitz continuous function.
However, if we try to use the calculus of variations to find the optimal solution, we’ll see that the Euler equation has no solution:
$$
f_X(x) = 0
$$
since $f_X(x)=1$ for $X \sim U(0,1)$.
The constraints almost entirely determine the form of $ g(x)$. It either takes a piecewise linear form, like $\max(x - c, 0)$, or it's identically zero. As a result, the optimal solution is easily seen to be $g^*(x) = x$.
I realize that it might not be appropriate to directly apply the Euler equation from standard textbooks on calculus of variations. But when I tried to derive the Euler equation starting from perturbations, I couldn’t find a place where the assumption of a bounded derivative comes into play.
Could someone point out what I might be missing or suggest a direction I should explore?

You have to augment the objective function to incorporate the constraints, like a Lagrange multiplier. Most books on optimal control will have this

what is $f_X$? when $X$ is that random variable?

... and if $f_X \ge0$ then $g(x) = x$ is the solution. As this is the 'largest' function possible under the constraints.

@whpowell96 Thanks. But I looked through some textbooks on optimal control, and there was almost no mention of bounded constraints on derivatives. Anyway, incorporating Lagrange seems to be one direction.

@daw Sorry to cause you trouble reading. I have updated some minor errors in the problem. As you mentioned, the optimal solution is easy to obtain. But how to get it from the point of view of variational method (or optimal control) is concerned.

You may be able to apply more standard theory from optimal control by considering the system
$$
\begin{aligned}
y'(x) &= g(x)f_X(x) \
g'(x) &= u(x) \
y(0)&=g(0)=0.
\end{aligned}
$$
The functional to be maximized is now just $y(1)$ and the constraint is a more standard control constraint $0\leq u(x) \leq 1$.
